# get_the_category() doesn't work outsideThe Loop?

Tags: functions, theme-development

I am trying to put the following code in the functions.php, to update a custom post's meta field whenever I publish a post.

```
function run_on_publish_post_only( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( ( 'publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status ) && 'post' === $post->post_type) {
        $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
        $args = array(
          'post_type'      => array('announcement'),
          'post_status'    => 'publish',
          'category'       => $categories[0]->term_id
                     );
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        update_post_meta($myposts[0]->ID,'latest_update',$post->ID);
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'run_on_publish_post_only', 10, 3 );
```

I narrowed down the problem to the get_the_cateogory(), it doesn't seem to retrieve a category object array.
Anything I missed?

Comment: Are you using a `do_action` to populate the `$post` variable anywhere in your code? It's not going to automatically fill with the `global $post` data.